# How to create url that opens hubspot company in notes tab

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm

I would like to link to a company in hubspot from our in-house system. Specifically, I want to link directly to the Activities page, on the Notes tab.

`https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/:portal-id/company/:company-id/view/1/` will get me to the Activities tab, vs `/contacts/:portal-id/company/:company-id/view/0/` going to the Overview.